# FieldCache with frequently updating index

Tags: c#, java, .net, lucene, lucene.net

Hi
I have lucene index that is frequently updating with new records, I have 5,000,000 records in my index and I'm caching one of my numeric fields using FieldCache. but after updating index it takes time to reload the FieldCache again (im reloading the cache cause documentation said DocID is not reliable) so how can I minimize this overhead by adding only newly added DocIDs to the FieldCache, cause this capability turns to bottleneck in my application.

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(diskDir);
int[] dateArr = FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts(reader, "newsdate"); // This line takes 4 seconds to load the array
dateArr = FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts(reader, "newsdate"); // this line takes 0 second as we expected
// HERE we add some document to index and we need to reload the index to reflect changes

reader = reader.Reopen();
dateArr = FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts(reader, "newsdate"); // This takes 4 second again to load the array
```

I want a mechanism that minimize this time by adding only newly added documents to the index in our array there is a technique like this http://invertedindex.blogspot.com/2009/04/lucene-dociduid-mapping-and-payload.html
to improve the performance but it still load all documents that we already have and i think there is no need to reload them all if we find a way to only adding newly added documents to the array

Comment: The problem with your code is what I describe with inner/outer readers. You're passing the outer reader, a DirectoryReader, to the FieldCache. It thinks that the two readers are different, and caches them separately. You need to use the innermost reader, the segment reader, to populate it per segment. This means that it will only load the changes after your call to Reopen. I'll post some code for this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FieldCache uses weak references to index readers as keys for their cache. (By calling `IndexReader.GetCacheKey` which has been un-obsoleted.) A standard call to `IndexReader.Open` with a `FSDirectory` will use a pool of readers, one for every segment.

You should always pass the innermost reader to the FieldCache. Check out `ReaderUtil` for some helper stuff to retrieve the individual reader a document is contained within. Document ids wont change within a segment, what they mean when describing it as unpredictable/volatile is that it will change between two index commits. Deleted documents could have been proned, segments have been merged, and such actions.

A commit needs to remove the segment from disk (merged/optimized away), which means that new readers wont have the pooled segment reader, and the garbage collection will remove it as soon as all older readers are closed.

Never, ever, call `FieldCache.PurgeAllCaches()`. It's meant for testing, not production use.

Added 2011-04-03; example code using subreaders.

```
var directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("index"));
var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, readOnly: true);
var documentId = 1337;

// Grab all subreaders.
var subReaders = new List<IndexReader>();
ReaderUtil.GatherSubReaders(subReaders, reader);

// Loop through all subreaders. While subReaderId is higher than the
// maximum document id in the subreader, go to next.
var subReaderId = documentId;
var subReader = subReaders.First(sub => {
    if (sub.MaxDoc() < subReaderId) {
        subReaderId -= sub.MaxDoc();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

var values = FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts(subReader, "newsdate");
var value = values[subReaderId];
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, but i want to make sure if i add new document to my index the document id of that doc would never change on merge or optimize cause if it changes then the above solution doesn't meet my needs cause i want to provide only newly added doc to the FieldCache to prevent loading all docs again using FieldCache, If i can make sure which segment reader remains intact during merge/optimize then i can surely load them according to your solution and reload other segment readers value and it is gradually improve the performance but it is still not ideal as i want

Comment: While technically the readers are intact after a merge/optimize, they are also obsoleted and replaced with the newly created segment. Could you provide some code examples that experience problems in your current setup?

Comment: Hi Simon, I have just read this post, and I was wondering - how does your solution work if a merge is currently running on a background thread?

Comment: @PiniSalim, excellent. The result of the merge will not be seen until the reader is reopened. The old segments (and their field caches) will be handled by the garbage collector once all old reader instances are closed (or garbage collected).

Comment: @Simon Svensson, if you build the FieldCache from old reader, doesnt it mean that the result array wont fit to the new merged segment? What I mean is, 'GatherSubReaders' gives you readers that are not up to date in case of a merge that currently runs on background thread, because the docIds might change at the end of the merge... Am I wrong? I would like to use your algorithm but I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: The newly created segment from the merge wont be used until your reader has been reopened, so document identifiers wont change [until the reader has been reopened]. The ReaderUtil class is part of the Lucene.Net assembly.

Comment: I see. The problem (for me..) is that I want to use the FieldCache during the search, so when I will open a reader - it will be updated AFTER merge, and the DocIds wont fit to those that were genereted with the FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetInts. Will it solve my problem if I will call WaitForMerges() on my IndexWriter, before calling GatherSubReaders and generating the FieldCache?

Comment: You can use the FieldCache during searches without any problems. Searchers are read-only, and wont cause any document id changes until the reader they are based on is reopened. Ask a new question if you have a reproducible problem with your Lucene.Net implementation.

Comment: @Simon Svensson: here is a link to the question I posted. Hope to hear your opinion :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110780/calling-commit-on-an-index-that-is-currently-been-merged-in-lucene

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I've solved this problem. You'll need to create a background thread to construct `IndexSearcher` instances, one at a time on some interval. Continue using your current `IndexSearcher` instance until a new one from the background thread is ready. Then swap out the new one to be your current one. Each instance acts as a snapshot of the index from the time that it was first opened. Note that the memory overhead for `FieldCache` doubles because you need two instances in memory at once. You can safely write to `IndexWriter` while this is happening.

If you need to you can take this a step further by making index changes immediately available for search, although it can get tricky. You'll need to associate a `RAMDirectory` with each snapshot instance above to keep the changes in memory. Then create a second `IndexWriter` that points to that `RAMDirectory`. For each index write you'll need to write to both `IndexWriter` instances. For searches you'll use a `MultiSearcher` across the `RAMDirectory` and your normal index on disk. The `RAMDirectory` can be thrown away once the `IndexSearcher` it was coupled with is no longer used. I'm glossing over some details here, however that's the general idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: suppose you have 1000 record in FSDirectory on disk and loading it using FieldCache and you have new 10 record in RAMDirectory as the way you explain above so we have two document with ID 0,...,10 cause each directory has its own docIDs and I cant create an integrated FieldCache with unique docID, and i also optimize my index after 10 times adding records. in this case docID could change.

Comment: The trick to the second part is that you'd be using a `MultiSearcher` across the `FSDirectory` and `RAMDirectory` such that the `FSDirectory` was opened before the `RAMDirectory` started getting changes. So it only appears to it that one of the two documents for a given ID exists. And the `MultiSearcher` handles merging the two when you perform searches. Unless you're using the `FieldCache` outside of search? I'd start with the first part though, open a second `IndexSearcher` (or `IndexReader`) instance in the background to let it build the `FieldCache` and then swap it out.

Comment: Yes i want to use FieldCache outside of search in CustomScoreQuery